# SQL Join Not Working Data present in Both the columns

Tags: sql, join

I am using the below query. PID that I looking for is present in both the tables. But when I use Join the result is from table2. I am not sure why this is happening. PID is varchar and PIDD is nvarchar I tried to convert in the join as well and No luck.

```
SELECT  
    a.PID,c.PIDD
FROM 
    Table1 a
LEFT JOIN
    Table2 c ON LTRIM(RTRIM(a.PID)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(c.PIDD)))
WHERE
    a.[ID] IN ('8200000')
```

Query output:

```
PID      PIDD
--------------
123      NULL
234      NULL
```

Comment: can you paste in your table data?

Comment: What do you mean "the result is from table2"?

Comment: What do you mean "the result is from table2"? c.PIDD column is coming as null even when there is data

Comment: can you paste in your table data? Sry I can't

Comment: To help you troubleshoot, try doing a Select *, just so you can see all of the columns returned from both tables.

Comment: "can you paste in your table data? Sry I can't" Then we can't help you.  Posting a broken query without any other information will not help us help you.

Comment: PID     PIDD
123    NULL
234   NULL

Comment: @SivaSagarKalagara can you post just those columns? a.pid and c.pidd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked.
De bugged using len()

LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PIDD, CHAR(10), CHAR(32)),CHAR(13), CHAR(32)),CHAR(160), CHAR(32)),CHAR(9),CHAR(32))))

Answer (score 0):

```
 PID that I looking for is present in both the tables.
```

Something about them must be different, even when you trim out the blank spaces.

```
PID is varchar and PIDD is nvarchar
```

Any chance PIDD has some characters that look alike, but are not actually the same character set, such as ' & `?

What happens when you query PIDD using the value returned from PID?  Is the value returned?  What do you have to change to get it to return the value you're looking for.

On a separate note, your performance will be terrible if you have to join your values using ltrim/rtrim.  `ltrim(rTRIM(a.PID)) = ltrim(rtrim(c.PIDD)))`

A table/index scan will be required regardless of any indexes on the table.

Comment: No Spl characters. PID returns the value and PIDD returns null.